# How to restrict changing env variable locally by batch file

Tags: batch-file

- I have two batch file x.bat and y.bat.
- I m calling y.bat from x.bat.
- File y.bat sets an env variable like:
  set ABC=
- Restriction is I cant change this Y.bat file but I want my variable "ABC" to be set as something else.
- How can I set "ABC" in X.bat so that it is not overriden by y.bat file set command.

Answer (score 1):

You can not avoid `y.bat` from changing the value in the variable. The environment variables can not be defined as constants nor be marked as readonly or write protected. If the called batch file changes the variable and you can not change the batch file, you can not avoid the change.

The only thing you can avoid is the propagation of the changes in the variable to affect the `x.bat`

**x.bat**

```dos
@echo off

    set "abc=set from x.bat"

    setlocal
    call y.bat
    endlocal

    echo %abc%
```

**y.bat**

```dos
@echo off
    set "abc=changed value"
```

`setlocal` generates a copy of the environment space and set this copy as active. All changes are done in this copy until the next `endlocal` that discards the copy, and restores the previous environment.

Answer (score 0):

In your batchfile set ABC to another var. You can do this as follows:

```
set DEF=%ABC%
```

an example:

```
set ABC=testing
set DEF=%ABC%
set ABC=changed

echo %ABC%
:: prints: changed

echo %DEF%
:: prints: testing
```

Comment: I dont want the variable name to be changed, since it has dependencies instead I do not want the set command to be read in Y.bat without making any changes in file Y.bat.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: You can of course set the var back after executing it. But you cannot force X.bat to use the value you specify in Y.bat if X.bat modifies that value.